# Copying files to different directories on FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

I'm wondering if there is any straightforward way to move files from one directory to another on an FTP server. I'm developing the software in Java and just want to automate some file duplication processes. I've done some hunting for 3rd party libraries, but I'm not finding much on copying files and directories on the same FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the Apache Net Commons, especially the FTP Client:
http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

There are some good examples at the top for connecting, logging in, and disconnecting.

I don't think the FTP protocol actually has a command for server-side file move, which may be why you're having trouble finding something for it. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp#List_of_FTP_commands ) Individual servers may offer extension commands though. If your server has a specific command for moving then you could issue it with the "doCommand(String command, String params)" method.

Alternatively, you could look into using something like SSH (instead of FTP) if your server allows it. That would let you run normal shell commands like mv and cp.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using the rename method of the [Apache Commons Net FTP client](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html), just indicate the absolute paths with the old and new directories in the from and to parameters respectively.